# Remove direct access to "/" on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, java-7

I have a spring boot application where i have only 2 endpoints defined.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllFeatures", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @Cacheable("features")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getAllFeatures() {
    ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/getFeatureStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @Cacheable("features")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getFeatureStatus(@RequestParam(value = "groupName", required = false) String groupName,
                @RequestParam(value = "featureName", required = false) String featureName) {
...
    }
```

And i have defined the context to be server.context-path=/abc

How the problem is when i do a GET call on /abc/ the application gives me a valid response. Where as i have never mapped "/" in my rest controller. Any ideas on how to block requests to "/". Also this application doesn't require any kind of spring security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
 @RequestMapping(path= "/getFeatureStatus"....)
```

instead of

```
  @RequestMapping(name = "/getFeatureStatus"....)
```

the name attribute just assigns a name to this mapping.

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'featuresController' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.util.controller.FeaturesController.getAllFeatures()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'featuresController' bean method`

Comment: I get the above exception

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. Didnt change it in the other method! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "/" endpoint is mapped to index.html file of your resource folder.
Does this file exist ? 
You also need to annotate your class with @RestController.